# Best Fit Line/Linear least squares fits

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

In my Physics intro/data analysis lecture, theres some mention of "Linear least squares fits":

> **Gradient**
>
> $$m = \frac{1}{\Delta} (N \sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i \sum y_i)$$
>
> $$\sigma_m = \sqrt{N \frac{\sigma^2 y}{\Delta}}$$
>
> **y-intercept**
>
> $$c = \frac{1}{\Delta} (\sum x_{i}^2 \sum y_i - \sum x_i \sum x_i
> > y_i$$
>
> $$\sigma \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2 y}{\Delta} \sum x_{i}^{2}}$$
>
> **Uncertainty for measured y**
>
> $$\sigma_y = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N-2} \sum (y_i - mx_i -c)^2}$$
>
> $$\Delta = N \sum x_{i}^{2} - (\sum x_i)^2$$
>
> **Coefficient of determination**
>
> $$r^2 = \frac{(N \sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i \sum y_i)^2}{(N \sum
> > x_{i}^{2} - (\sum x_i)^2) (N \sum y_i^2 - (\sum y_i)^2)}$$
>
> - $r^2 = 0$: no corelation
> - $r^2 = 1$: perfect correlation

Main question is whats $\Delta$.

And if its simple, it'll be good to have a little understanding about how the formulas are defined. Just something very rough or a simple explaination

Answer (score 2):

$\Delta$ is called *sample variance* please have a look at :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence

if $x$ is the true value and $y$ is the estimate, least squares fitting fits each $y$ to $x$ such that the mean squared error between $x$ and $y$ is minimized.

in order to determine the $y_i$ one needs to take the derivative of the objective function and make it equal to zero. vector $y$ is the solution of this minimization.

*gradient* corresponds to this derivation operation.

*uncertainty for measured y* indicated the quality of the fit as it gives the error between the true values $y$ and the linear fit $mx_i+c$

*coeffficient r* is gives you another measure of the goodness of the fit. If you have $r^2=1$ then this corresponds to perfect fit!

Comment: Ok, I took a look at the wiki, but I dont really see how do I get $\Delta$, if its there then I'm not sure which 1 is it?

Comment: @JiewMeng when you look at the second $r_{xy}$, there are two terms in the denominator in the square root. Pick one of them. Lets sat the one which is $\sqrt{n\sum_i x_i^2-(\sum_i x_i)^2}=\sigma$ and what you have is exactly $\sigma^2=\Delta$